# Using ffmpeg To Convert wav file to g729 file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg` in my Windows laptop to convert `.wav` to `.g729` format. I have spent some times on the documentation, tutorials, and some threads with no success till now.

Below is my `ffmpeg` version details:

`ffmpeg version N-89674-g57d0c24132 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-amf --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
libavformat    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
libavfilter     7.  8.100 /  7.  8.100
libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100`

I have tried `ffmpeg -i testA.wav -c:a libavformat -f g.729 output.g729` and ended up with error saying `[NULL @ 0000022aa639dd80] Requested output format 'g.729' is not a suitable output format
output.g729: Invalid argument`.

I did try some different format names with no success still.

Appreciate some guidance on this. Thanks.

Comment: FFmpeg has no G729 encoder. bcg729 can do it but you'll have to compile it - http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/bcg729/overview

Comment: @Mulvya oh i thought FFmpeg has G729 encoder. What do you mean I'll have to compile it? I looked into the link but not quite sure how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Mulvya said, ffmpeg does not support G729 encoding, only decoding. Have a look here: http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#Audio-Codecs

> **2.4 Audio Codecs**
> `Name    Encoding    Decoding`
> `...`
> `G.729                  X`

But instead of ffmpeg you can use the suggested implementation of the bcg729 en-/decoder.

Download the sources from here https://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/bcg729 via git and compile it by yourself.

Because you have windows (linux would be a better choice for this case ;)) you need a working compiler. Try Cygwin with GCC, there are many tutorials.

A good start could be this one: https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/cygwin/

Comment: thank you for the guidance. My server is in Linux (Ubuntu), but to understand what needs done, this should be a good start. Quick one, any idea if G711mu-law encode/decode is supported too by ffmpeg? I am actually working on encode/decode for both G729 and G711mu-law.

Comment: @UserProg Never heard from G711 before. And ffmpeg page has no entry about decoding/encoding, so you can be sure that this codec isn't supported. I think you have to search for a library. PS: Linux should make it easy to compile bcg729, otherwise feel free to ask.

Comment: it seems that I have the library installed in my Ubuntu server (correctly I hope). I ran `./configure -V` and got response `bcg729 configure 1.0.0
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69 Copyright..........`. But I have not enough understanding how it works. Is this library something like ffmpeg where I can simply use command to encode wav file to g729 file?

Comment: The default way to compile such applications is to run `./configure`, then `make` and `make install`. `configure` only prepares the build, but doesn't compile. `make` is the compile step, here a binary is build. `make install` can be used to install the app in your system (so in most cases you would call `sudo make install`. I give it a try when I'm at home. To successfully build you often need more packages from ubuntu like gcc and so on. `configure` should told you what is missing.

Comment: thanks for the response. i think i have installed the library but I totally have no idea how to run it..appreciate some guidance..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this repositories doesn't contains executable files, only library for that codec.
Can't find a way to correctly use this codec the same way as ffmpeg encoding/decoding process.